# CakePHP: One column -> one TRUE

Tags: database, cakephp, boolean, cakephp-2.0

Hope someone could help me with this:

I would like to have a column that will contain one and only one `TRUE` value. I want to set a value of `TRUE` (or '1') to a row and be assured that the remaining rows are `FALSE` (or '0').

How this could be achieved with CakePHP?

Comment: Set all rows to `false`, then set one row to `true`...?

Comment: Could you specify why you want this? I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enforce this at the database level (well, you can if you use triggers) so you'll have to enforce it using Model::beforeSave()

Something along the lines of:

```
public function afterSave() {

    if ($this->data['Model']['field'] == 1) {
        // set all other records to false
        $this->updateAll(array('field'=>0));
    }

}
```

When the record is saved, it should be the only one with 'field' set to true.

Comment: I'd still be tempted to do it after save just in case something fails during the save.

Comment: Wouldn't the `updateAll` in the `afterSave` also set the row which just got appointed 1 for `field` to 0?

Comment: Ah, good catch perterbond >.< - needs a condition adding to ignore the newly updated/inserted row